# MatrixRETS get data with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mls

I'm working on a **Real Estate** project with Ruby on Rails based on **Florida**, there are no more details about `matrixrets.swflamls` API but I need fetch data from there database save to my own database this regular basis for data update and create.

I have following configuration for fetching data

```
client = Rets::Client.new({
    login_url: 'http://matrixrets.swflamls.com/rets/Login.ashx',
    username: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    password: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
})
```

Query for fetching data, this query copied from this [tutorial](https://www.flexmls.com/developers/rets/tutorials/dmql-tutorial/), this tutorial is related but not exact for my API

```
properties = client.find (:all), {
    search_type: 'Property',
    class: 'RES',
    querytype: 'DMQL2',
    Format: 'COMPACT',
    query: "(YearBuilt=1900+), (Status=A)",
}

<% properties.each do |data| %>
   <%= data['Bedrooms'] %>
<% end %>
```

I have some keys for properties like active, pending etc... the below

```
'A', 'AC', 'AP', 'AS', 'I', 'P', 'PC', 'R', 'T', 'W'
```

I have two questions:

1. How to fetch data from there database
2. If I got data then how to all data fetch like Status equal all keys.

Currently not any error also not fetching any data

Much appriciated

Comment: Have you debugged the `data` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think you have missed something in you your configuration section if you got the [RETSMD](https://retsmd.com/) for looking details on your API you found the `version` I think you missed the version see the below.

```
client = Rets::Client.new({
      login_url: 'http://matrixrets.swflamls.com/rets/Login.ashx',
      username: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      password: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      version: 'RETS/1.7.2' #=> Or which compatible yours like 1.5 or something
})
```

Then update your query using `no_records_not_an_error` method for if not find data then not showing any error else will show a nil error, see the below

```
properties = client.find (:all), {
    no_records_not_an_error: true,
    search_type: 'Property',
    class: 'RES',
    querytype: 'DMQL2',
    Format: 'COMPACT',
    query: "(YearBuilt=1900+), (Status=A})",
}
```

That your problem 1

Hope that is work

Now problem 2

You can declare an array and keep all keys inside array like below

```
    arr = ['A', 'AC', 'AP', 'AS', 'I', 'P', 'PC', 'R', 'T', 'W']
```

And then update your query

```
for i in 0...arr.count
    properties = client.find (:all), {
        no_records_not_an_error: true,
          search_type: 'Property',
          class: 'RES',
          querytype: 'DMQL2',
          Format: 'COMPACT',
          query: "(YearBuilt=1900+), (Status=#{arr[i]})",
    }

    puts properties.count #=> count for every status
end
```

See the console have counted any number if yes then working and then move forward.

Hope it helps

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks @fool-dev